# sed add line at the end of file

Tags: shell, sed, freebsd, csh

I trying to add a line at the end of file (/root/test.conf) with sed. I use FreeBSD and when I try to add a simple line, I always get several errors like:

- extra characters at the of command
- undefined label 'est.conf'

The file is like this:

```
#Test
firstLine
secondLine

!p.p
*.*
```

And I want to add something like this:

```
(return \n)
!word
other (5 tab between "other" and "/usr/local") /usr/local
```

If it's not possible with sed, there are another options?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need to use sed at all, maybe just `cat` with a heredoc:

```
cat >>test.conf <<EOF
whatever you want here

more stuff
EOF
```

`>>` opens `test.conf` in "append" mode, so lines are added to the bottom of the file, and the `<<EOF` is a heredoc that allows you to pass lines to cat via standard input.

To add literal tabs in the interactive terminal, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Notice that for the specific example in the question, you might have to quote `EOF` or the `!` could cause history expansion problems.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any special tools like sed to add some lines to the end of files.

```
$ echo "This is last line" >>file 
#or
$ printf "This is last line\n" >>file
```

works just fine in almost any platform. You might need to escape special characters though, or enclose them in single/double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In the event you have other things to do in sed, and appending at the end is just one of them:

```
sed -e "\$a A-line-at-the-end.' <infile >outfile
sed -e '$a A-Line-at-the-end.'  <infile >outfile
sed -e '$a\A-line-at-the-end.'  <infile >outfile
```

Works on linux (ubuntu), not on freebsd.

Comment: This just says `sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated address regex`

Comment: It appears to only work on linux (tested ubuntu 21), not bsd (freebsd).  The leading char must be a '\', not a '/' if using double quotes.  If single quotes, no backslash required.  Also, the first character after the 'a' for "append" is discarded; the man page says it must be a backslash but it seems to work with any char.  I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, the last one works for me on Linux, but you have a closing double-quote on the last two lines instead of a closing single quote.  Might I suggest changing the command to `echo -e "one\ntwo" | sed ...`?  That way you can copy and paste it onto the command line to test it, without needing to create `infile` or `outfile`.

Comment: That's certainly a valid option.  I prefer explicitly showing input and output redirection in examples; the user familiar with redirection can embellish as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this recently. I am not sure if anyone will even need this and I am sure there is probably better way to do this.

Disclaimer: I was using FreeBSD and sed there is a little bit different then other os.

So I came up with this:
`sed -i '' -e '$s/$/\ntext1=\"text2\"/g' /location/file.test`

explained: `sed -i '' -e`

`-i` extension = Edit files in-place

`-e` command = Append the editing commands

`- s/regular expression/replacement/flags`

explained: `'$s/$/\ntext1=\"text2\"/g' /location/file.test`

`$s` = last line

`$/` = end of line

`\ntext1=\"text2\"` = add text start with `\n` = newline followed by text

`/g`  = Make the  substitution  for  all  non-overlapping matches

`/location/file.test` = path of the file you are editing

Alternative examples

at the start of  the document: `sed -i '' -e '1s/^/text1=\"text2\"\n/g' /location/file.test`

at the line 3: `sed -i '' -e '3s/^/text1=\"text2\"\n/g' /location/file.test`